# pass arguments to a function php

Tags: php, arrays

Is it possible to convert an array to a list of elements without using list?

---

**this works well**

```
list($arg_a,$arg_b) = array($foo,$bar);
myfunction($arg_a,$arg_b);
```

but I'm looking for something similar to that:

```
$array = array($foo,$bar);
myfunction(php_builtin_function(array($foo,$bar)));
```

**obviusly I can't edit that function!**

```
function myfunction($param_a,$param_b){
    ...
    }
```

Comment: You are looking for `call_user_func_array()`: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php

Comment: `myfunction($ar[0], $ar[1]);` OR `myfunction($ar['foo'], $ar['bar']);` if associative array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, here's what you need:

```
call_user_func_array('myfunction', php_builtin_function(array($foo,bar)));
```

[Docs](http://php.net/call-user-func-array)

That said, it would be more readable to use `list`:

```
$result = php_builtin_function(array($foo,$bar));
list($arg_a, $arg_b) = $result;
myfunction($arg_a, $arg_b);
```

Comment: Reading the question, I think it should just be: `call_user_func_array('myfunction', array($foo, $bar));`. `php_builtin_function` is just an imaginary function converting the array to single function arguments.